# Caching huge data in memory using java

Tags: java, memory-management, spring-mvc

I am working on web based java application dealing with huge amount of inventory items say 400K-500K. Description of the current solution is as follow.

Inventory fields (min 20 - max 30)

Field Length (Varies from 1 - 255)

Field Types (varies)

Currently we store inventory in database after some validations (comparison with old records, create versions etc...). Inventory data in updated multiple times a day and same process is run every time on new inventory.

We have APIs which expose this data to multiple third party websites (consumers). The websites make 8-10 API calls per page and if there is a heavy traffic on websites then the APIs get slow.

To overcome this, I am working on a proposal to store this data in memory and serve the request directly. My initial estimates are between 8-20GB. Obviously it will require some more memory when I wrap this data into java objects.

Any suggestions/recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use an existing caching framework, such as EhCache.

Comment: [memcached](http://memcached.org/) might be right for you.

Comment: will that help in reducing the amount of memory used? also, how about compressing the data in memory and decompressing when required?

Comment: If you're trying to speed things up then this probably isn't a good approach. And the effectiveness of compression depends on the structure of your data.